# Perl Export Suggestions

Tags: perl, perl-exporter

I am working with a new program that needs to interface with perl.

The example code suggests that all of the methods will be exported to the global namespace like below:

```
use BGPmon::Fetch;
my $ret = init_bgpdata();
my $ret = connect_bgpdata();
my $xml_msg = read_xml_message();
...
```

However using any of the methods like that causes "`Undefined subroutine &Fetch::init_bgpdata`." I know the module works but doesn't seem to be exporting correctly because I can still use the long names: `BGPmon::Fetch::init_bgpdata();`.

Any reason why the module isn't exporting correctly?

Note: I would love to share the method code but I know its not a problem with the module. It is part of a codeset I can't share and I know it works because the tests manage to pass.

### Exporter Section

```
require Exporter;
our $AUTOLOAD;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw(connect_bgpdata read_xml_message
  close_connection is_connected messages_read uptime connection_endtime
  get_error_code get_error_message get_error_msg) ] );
our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );
```

[Public source code](http://bgpmon.netsec.colostate.edu/index.php/download) (mine is the dev)

Comment: I am very new to perl. I tried `print BGPmon::Fetch::@EXPORT` and got nothing. Am I doing this wrong or was that expected?

Comment: How about look/post relevant part of the module source? :)

Comment: Updated some of the details. The public version isn't too far behind mine but because I don't own the code, I can't release the dev without permission.

Comment: Does `use BGPmon::Fetch qw(init_bgpdata);` work?

Comment: No, it freaks out about that not being exported by this module... Which doesn't seem right. (Might be a flaw of the dev version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you have given, you are defining a tag `:all`

So you calling code can do

```
use  BGPmon::Fetch ':all' ;
```

Alternatively you can import them individually

```
use BGPmon::Fetch qw(init_bgpdata connect_bgpdata); # and so on
```

It is worth having a look at [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) - apologies if already done so

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction. I can't seem to import init_bgpdata because it says its not exported by this module. I was reading in the Exporter documents about matching package names. Do I need to be using a package name or is that for the module?

Comment: you need to add  `init_bgpdata` to the list of subroutines you are exporting. The code works fine with `connect_bgpdata` which is listed

Comment: Seems to be a flaw I will bring up at the meeting tomorrow. Thank you!